# Is there a way to add a login with the sysadmin role for SQL Server using Ansible?

Tags: sql-server, ansible, yaml

I am reading through the Ansible documentation for the Database Modules and there does not seem to be anything that goes into how to add logins with the role of sysadmin in SQL Server.

Is there any possible workaround in Ansible to do this?

Comment: Logins are added by executing SQL commands, no matter what tool is used. When you create a new user in SSMS you can click on `Script` instead of `OK` to generate the `CREATE LOGIN` command

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can the `CREATE LOGIN` command be used within an Ansible YAML playbook to automate this task?